Axis 1.4 not setting correct type of parameter
i am trying to communicate to an API (an outdated one at that, as you can tell by my use of Axis 1.4), and been having trouble setting the type of the parameter. I am defining and adding it to the operation like:
oper = new OperationDesc();
param = new ParameterDesc(
        new QName("", "parameters"), ParameterDesc.IN,
        new QName("http://exampleuri.org", "input"),
        Input.class, false, false
);
oper.addParameter(param);

Where Input is the Java class generated by Axis for this service.
However, when the call is invoked, the resulting tag ends up being <parameters xsi:type="xsd:string">, with simpletype "string" instead of <parameters xsi:type="xsd:input"> , using the the informed complextype "input", forcing characters such as < to become &lt;, which is not accepted by the service. Replacing the characters makes the request work on SoapUI.I understand how this is a small problem, however i have not been able to find any solution to it.
